# How do I remove negative frequencies after a Fourier transform?

Tags: filtering, fft

I use a Java library to perform a Fast Fourier Transform on some two dimensional meteorological data (longitude and time) of size nx and nt. After the transform, I get a complex array of size 2*nx and nt, where 2*nx and 2*nx+1 indices represent a complex number with real and imaginary parts. For each time frequency, there are complex numbers in the spatial frequency dimension which are complex conjugates, so the numbers from indices 1 to nx/2 are complex conjugates of the numbers from nx/2+1 to nx. I understand the complex numbers from nx/2 to nx represent negative wavenumbers.

My question is: how do I remove the negative wavenumbers before inverse transforming? I only want to retain waves with positive wavenumber and frequency, but if I set the complex numbers from nx/2+1 to nx to zero then transform back, I get a complex array, and I'm not sure how to interpret this or find a real array equivalent which represents only the positive frequencies and wavenumbers. Can anyone guide me on how to filter out negative wavenumbers and get something back that has physical meaning i.e. real numbers?

Comment: If you want the inverse transform to be real-valued, then you need the frequency domain to have the complex conjugate symmetry. You cannot set the “negative” frequencies to zero because then you don’t have the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

The way to "retain waves with positive wavenumber" and get a strictly real result from a full complex IFFT is to make sure the array you feed the IFFT is conjugate symmetric, as the conjugate symmetry what causes all the imaginary components in the IFFT result to cancel out to zero (or very near zero with some tiny rounding "errors" or numerical noise).

There may be inverse real FFT implementations in your library that will do this for you, e.g. take a half-size complex array as input and internally synthesize the conjugate symmetry needed to output a strictly real result.